Science-fiction movie about people warping to a frozen space station
I'm looking for a movie where the main guy has a wife and he is on a strike team that goes to other worlds. He tells his wife this is his last mission, goes to work, then there is some sort of attack from the colony they are suppose to go to. 
They warp there with a device you plug into that sends you to the destination. Once they get there everything is frozen and they have to find this one guy and bring him home. 
They warm up the place by getting the power back on but crazy stuff starts to happen and the strike team starts tripping out on each other and everyone goes crazy hostile and murderous. Then all this stuff happens and at the end they all are like standing there like wtf and everyone is alive again and they warp back home. 
It is kind of like Dead Space! But what is it called?

Also I remember when they travel like as they come back they are only actually gone for like 7 minutes or some crazy short time and they have to answer a bunch of questions like who are you what's your name what was your mission like the doc team asks them to make sure they aren't crazy but they just had that crazy experience so they are all pretty good. It it's kinda tense

Figured it out.... Infini :) gonna have a good watch tonight

Hello @Mathew Haller, welcome to Movies & TV. Glad you figured it out. In the future, if you want to add on to your question, just use the edit feature. A comment which isn't actually a comment will most likely be deleted. Thanks!

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

This sounds very much like Infini (2015) directed by Shane Abbess.
Here is the IMDB link with the trailer and more info: 
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3327624/ 
Reasons (using OP's description and various plot summaries):

" Have to find this one guy and bring him home "

IMDB: "An elite 'search and rescue' team transport onto an off-world mining-facility to rescue Whit Carmichael, the lone survivor of a biological outbreak."

" everything is frozen "

Wikipedia: "Arriving, they find a frozen slaughterhouse"

" crazy stuff starts happening "

Wikipedia: " They begin to become enraged and violent "
Also a quick watch of this: 

 and it fits with the OP's description! 
EDIT: just seen your comment on the original post... d'oh!

Still a valid answer. It's better than answering in the comments. Here, take my upvote. But if you edit your answer to add details on why this is the correct movie, that would make your answer even better.

Thanks, I've edited with comments from the plot summary and the trailer for the movie - I've not answered an identify-this-movie question before so I hope my reasoning is OK!
